How to Configure Nginx to Serve a Kotlin Multiplatform Project Wasm Website Built with Gradle?
I am working with a Kotlin Multiplatform project that you can view here on GitHub. I started by using the Kotlin Multiplatform Wizard and selected the Web platform option, everything else remains unchanged.
Here's what I've done:

Ran the ./gradlew build command.
When I attempt to open the index.html file directly, either one of this directories,the page remains blank.
However, when I run ./gradlew wasmJsBrowserProductionWebpack, the site launches successfully and is served by the WebPack server.

I would like to serve this project using Nginx instead of WebPack.
I would appreciate guidance on setting up the nginx.conf file for this purpose.
